# mahout configuration bug, how to fix it

Tags: java, hadoop, mahout

mahout-0.9 doesn't work at all. i download the binary package and set the envionment variables.

when command mahout --help
it reports

```
WARN driver.MahoutDriver；
Uable to add class:org.apache.mahout.math.hadoop.similarity.cooccurence.RowSimilarityJob
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/JobContext
hadoop2.2,mahout0.9
```

I thought it's classpath problem, i found JobContext include in the hadoop2.2.0-core.jar,but after i set classpath, it still doesn't work.

any ideas? 
cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mahout 0.9 does not support Hadoop 2.  The upcoming 1.0 release will.  If you want to use Mahout with Hadoop 2, you'll have to build from the most recent source and specify the Hadoop profile.  Instructions for doing so are here:  http://mahout.apache.org/developers/buildingmahout.html